# Excute java class from python with extrnal jar and multiple args

Tags: java, python, linux, python-3.x

I'm trying to build script to execute java class with passing data sample and getting the result from java. The java code uses external jar which already in the same path of my python file and java file

my script in python :

```py
import os.path,subprocess
from subprocess import STDOUT,PIPE

def compile_java(java_file):
    subprocess.check_call(['javac', '-cp', 'commons-codec-1.7.jar', java_file])

def execute_java(java_file,args):
    java_class,ext = os.path.splitext(java_file)
    cmd = ['java', '-cp', 'commons-codec-1.7.jar', java_class]
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
    stdout,stderr = proc.communicate(args)
    print(stdout)
compile_java('jf.java')
execute_java('jf.java',[1,2])
```

my java class sample:

```java
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
public class jf {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(args[0]);

    }
}
```

but i got errors while compling :

```py
b'Error: Could not find or load main class jf\n'
```

I think the problem is with passing `args` to the main function, and how could i return value from java while main function is `void` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specify a classpath to java through the `-cp` parameter. Java will look for the jf class in the given files and won't find it :

```sh
> java -cp commons-codec-1.7.jar jf toot
Error: Could not find or load main class jf
```

You don't really need `commons-codec` here. You may directly use the class name :

```sh
> java jf toot
toot
```

Or add `.` to your classpath if your real code needs additionnal jars :

```sh
> java -cp commons-codec-1.7.jar;. jf toot
toot
```

In your python :

```py
cmd = ['java', '-cp', 'commons-codec-1.7.jar;.', java_class]
```

One additionnal point : as you need to pass arguments, I would not use `proc.communicate` as it send the data on the standard input (you need to use something like scanner in the java side), but simply append `args` to you `cmd` array:

```py
cmd = ['java', '-cp', 'commons-codec-1.7.jar;.', java_class] + args
```

Comment: Note that this code is for windows. On linux, the separator is `:` for the classpath elements.

Comment: Thanks alot, now it works but regarding the output that java gave me, i use system,out.println to get output from java but is there any other way better to collect outputs from java ?

Comment: You're basically trying to do cross process communication. Many would call this Remote Procedure Call (RPC). Using arguments, stdin and stdout at the easiest way to do it. For one shot processes, that's surely more than enough. For long running processes, you may try to use socket communication, but that's really more complex.

Answer (score 1):

I think this code should work:

```
cmd = ['java', java_class, 'InputString']
```

Comment: i need to pass list not string, i tried to pass the list or even string in the cmd but still the same problem